# How to work this equation out backwards to find the variable from the value?

Tags: functions, logarithms, graphing-functions

There is a question that is asking me ($N$=number of hectares destroyed) ($t$=hours since passed) where the function for finding land that is burned out is

$N=40 \log_{10}(500t+1)$

it wants me to find the amount of time ($t$) until the hectares (land) burned is $155$. How do i work backwards to get the time until the specified land amount is burned out.

I just want to know any function or how to use this function to get the time until the specified amount of hectares ($155$) is burned out. 
Thank you.

Comment: You have to rearrange the equation until you have isolated $t$ on one side. The inverse function of $\log_10$ is $10^\cdot$.

Answer (score 3):

You have

$$N = 40\log_{10}(500t + 1) \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

You can rearrange this to get $t$ in terms of $N$ by dividing, taking the values to the power of $10$, and a few other manipulations, to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{N}{40} & = \log_{10}(500t + 1) \\
10^{N/40} & = 500t + 1 \\
10^{N/40} - 1 & = 500t \\
t & = \frac{10^{N/40} - 1}{500}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

With $N = 155$, \eqref{eq2} gives $t = 14.99\ldots$ , i.e., basically $15$ hours.